# Salesforce OIDC with AWS ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer, sfdc

I am setting up AWS ALB to authenticate using OIDC.

I am getting the below response:  error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=redirect_uri%20must%20match%20configuration

How should this be handled.

And for AWS ALB be able to authenticate is there anything special to be done in SFDC side

Comment: That means that the redirect_uri from your Login-Flow is not on the Allowlist in your Cognito-Configuration.

Comment: i am not using cognito. so where exactly i have the change required. its in salesforce idp or in alb

Comment: My bad, I read ALB authentication and redirect_uri and my mind immediately jumped to Cognito ;-) - I seem to recall configuring it on the Cognito-End, so probably in Salesforce